# Spring Cloud Data Flow server behind HTTP proxy

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

With version 2.5.3 setting https.proxyHost, https.proxyPort and http.nonProxyHosts system properties was enough to let the server to talk outside. For example, it could retrieve metadata of docker images in Docker Hub.

I'm testing 2.7.0 now and this is not enough anymore. What is the correct way of configuring HTTP proxy?

The [ContainerRegistryAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/8644a5cdef59e5fba6456c200ef626575820862b/spring-cloud-dataflow-container-registry/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/container/registry/ContainerRegistryAutoConfiguration.java#L187) uses HttpClients.custom(). Is this the reason?

The error, after enabling debug logging is

```
2020-12-17 10:40:42.048  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver : Failed to retrieve properties for resource Docker Resource [docker:springcloudstream/file-source-kafka:2.1.2.RELEASE] because of ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)2020-12-17 10:40:42.048  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver : Failed to retrieve properties for resource Docker Resource [docker:springcloudstream/file-source-kafka:2.1.2.RELEASE] because of ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)2020-12-17 10:40:42.048 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver : (Details) for failed to retrieve properties for resource:Docker Resource [docker:springcloudstream/file-source-kafka:2.1.2.RELEASE]
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://auth.docker.io/token": Connect to auth.docker.io:443 [auth.docker.io/52.72.232.213, auth.docker.io/107.23.149.57, auth.docker.io/3.218.162.19, auth.docker.io/54.236.131.166, auth.docker.io/52.4.20.24, auth.docker.io/54.85.56.253, auth.docker.io/34.195.246.183, auth.docker.io/52.20.56.50] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to auth.docker.io:443 [auth.docker.io/52.72.232.213, auth.docker.io/107.23.149.57, auth.docker.io/3.218.162.19, auth.docker.io/54.236.131.166, auth.docker.io/52.4.20.24, auth.docker.io/54.85.56.253, auth.docker.io/34.195.246.183, auth.docker.io/52.20.56.50] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:746) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:712) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:600) at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.container.registry.authorization.DockerOAuth2RegistryAuthorizer.getAuthorizationHeaders(DockerOAuth2RegistryAuthorizer.java:116)
.........................
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to auth.docker.io:443 [auth.docker.io/52.72.232.213, auth.docker.io/107.23.149.57, auth.docker.io/3.218.162.19, auth.docker.io/54.236.131.166, auth.docker.io/52.4.20.24, auth.docker.io/54.85.56.253, auth.docker.io/34.195.246.183, auth.docker.io/52.20.56.50] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:737)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 87 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for catching this. As you would know, we have a PR in the works ([spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#4296](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/pull/4296)) and when that is merged, it'd be great if you could try the SNAPSHOT build in your environment before we ship 2.7.1.

Feel free to also weigh-in on the PR changes, too. Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I forgot to update this post. In https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/4295 I expressed my concern about the proposed changes. 

I'm on vacations till January 4th. Then I can see how to put the SNAPSHOT into docker images